# Integrating a ParametricNDSolve solution whose initial conditions are determined by another ParametricNDSolve function?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, boundary-conditions

I am trying integrate a ParametricNDSolve output (System2) whose initial conditions vary according to another ParametricNDSolve function (System1). The code I have so far is as follows.

```
a = 3/100; b = d2 = 1; HMax = 1000;c=0.5;

System1 = 
  ParametricNDSolve[{X'[t] == X[t]*b*H[t]/HMax - X[t]*X[t]*d2/K1, 
    H'[t] == -a*H[t], X[0] == K1, H[0] == HMax}, {X, H}, {t, 0, 
    5000}, {K1}];

System2 = 
  ParametricNDSolve[{X'[t] == X[t]*b*H[t]/HMax - X[t]*(X[t]+Y[t])*d2/K1, 
    H'[t] == -a*H[t], Y'[t]==Y[t]*b*H[t]/HMax*(1-c)-Y[t]*d2*(Y[t]+X[t])/K1,X[0] == X[K1][t0] /. System1, 
    H[0] == H[K1][t0] /. System1,Y[0]=1}, {X, H}, {t, 0, 5000}, {K1, t0}];

Function1[K1_, t0_] := 
  NIntegrate[X[K1, t0][t] /. System2, {t, 0, 1000}];

NIntegrate[Function1[1000, t0], {t0, 0, 100}]
```

This code gives me an NIntegrate error that says "the integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1000}}."

Is there a way around this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: `X[1000, t0][t] /. System2` is a function of both `t` and `t0`.  Integrating over `t0` still leaves it as a function of `t`.  Is that what you are seeking?

Comment: Also, in your real problem, as opposed to this simple case, are the ODEs in `System1` and `System2` still the same as each other, or do they differ?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Hello! Thank you so much for your response. I updated the code. It was missing an integral. The real equations are such that System 2 has an extra variable but, in the absence of that extra variable, System1 would be the same as System 2.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I added the third variable, Y[t], to System2. Basically, my goal is to have system2 to behave as if Y[t] is not present until time t0. Then I want to integrate Function1 with respect to t0.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Fixed it! Apologies for the unorganized post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem can be solved using `ParametricNDSolve` twice, but a simpler approach is to use `ParametricNDSolve` once together with `Piecewise`.

```
System = ParametricNDSolveValue[
   {X'[t] == Piecewise[{{X[t]*b*H[t]/HMax - X[t]*(X[t] + Y[t])*d2/K1, t > t0}},
        X[t]*b*H[t]/HMax - X[t]*X[t]*d2/K1], 
    H'[t] == -a*H[t], 
    Y'[t] == Piecewise[{{Y[t]*b*H[t]/HMax*(1 - c) - Y[t]*d2*(Y[t] + X[t])/K1, t > t0}}],
    X[0] == K1, H[0] == HMax, Y[0] == 1}, 
    {X[t], H[t], Y[t]}, {t, 0, 5000}, {K1, t0}];
```

A typical solution is

```
LogPlot[Evaluate[System[1000, 30] /. t -> t + 30], {t, 0, 1000}, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, "X,H,Y"}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

(Note that the range has been shifted to take account that only `t > t0` is desired.)

[image]

Now, to obtain the integral, define

```
f[t0_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Evaluate[First[System[1000, t0]]], {t, t0, 1000 + t0}]
```

and the desired result is

```
NIntegrate[f[t0], {t0, 0, 100}]
(* 1.60042*10^6 *)
```

For completeness, `f` can be plotted.

```
Plot[f[t0], {t0, 0, 100}, AxesLabel -> {t0, f}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is extremely helpful.

Comment: It is a nice solution (+1).

Answer (score 4):

As a second opinion to a nice solution by bbgodfrey, we can also use `Module` instead of `ParametricNDSolve` as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]

a = 3/100; b = d2 = 1; HMax = 1000; c = 0.5;

x[k_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ, ts_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{K1 = k, t0 = T}, {X0, H0} = 
   NDSolveValue[{X'[t] == X[t]*b*H[t]/HMax - X[t]*X[t]*d2/K1, 
     H'[t] == -a*H[t], X[0] == K1, H[0] == HMax}, {X[t0], H[t0]}, {t, 
     0, 5000}];
  Xs = NDSolveValue[{X'[t] == 
      X[t]*b*H[t]/HMax - X[t]*(X[t] + Y[t])*d2/K1, H'[t] == -a*H[t], 
     Y'[t] == Y[t]*b*H[t]/HMax*(1 - c) - Y[t]*d2*(Y[t] + X[t])/K1, 
     X[0] == X0, H[0] == H0, Y[0] == 1}, X[ts], {t, 0, 5000}]; Xs]
```

Visualization of `X`

```
Plot3D[x[1000, T, ts], {ts, 0, 1000}, {T, 0, 100}, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue, Mesh -> None, AxesLabel -> {"t", "t0", "X"}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Finally we can integrate

```
NIntegrate[x[1000, T, ts], {ts, 0, 1000}, {T, 0, 100}]

Out[]= 1.60042*10^6
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

My first attempt was misleaded by the fact, that OP uses th same names H and X in both systems for different functions. That is bad practice !

Now got the same result as @bbgodfrey, doing a few calculations analyticaly.

```
a = 3/100; b = d2 = 1; HMax = 1000; c = 1/2;

(eqs1 = {X'[t] == X[t]*b*H[t]/HMax - X[t]*X[t]*d2/K1, 
H'[t] == -a*H[t], X[0] == K1, H[0] == HMax}) //  TableForm

Hsol = H /. First@DSolve[{eqs1[[{2, 4}]]}, H, t]

Plot[Hsol[t], {t, 0, 500}, PlotRange -> All]

Xsol[K1_] = X /. First@DSolve[{eqs1[[{1, 3}]]} /. H ->  Hsol, X, t]

Plot3D[Xsol[K1][t], {t, 0, 200}, {K1, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]

(eqs2 = {X'[t] == X[t]*b*H[t]/HMax - X[t]*(X[t] + Y[t])*d2/K1, 
 H'[t] == -a*H[t], 
 Y'[t] == Y[t]*b*H[t]/HMax*(1 - c) - Y[t]*d2*(Y[t] +  X[t])/K1, 
 X[0] == (X[t0] /. X -> Xsol[K1]), H[0] == (H[t0] /. H -> Hsol), 
 Y[0] == 1}) // Simplify // TableForm

(eqs3 = eqs2 /. {X -> X2, H -> H2}) // TableForm

H2sol[t0_] = H2 /. First@DSolve[{eqs3[[2]], eqs3[[5]]}, H2, t]

eqs4[K1_, t0_] = DeleteCases[eqs3 /. H2 -> H2sol[t0], True]

ndsol2[K1_, t0_] := First@NDSolve[eqs4[K1, t0], {X2, Y}, {t, 0, 1000}]

LogPlot[Evaluate[{X2[t],
Y[t], H2sol[30][t]} /. ndsol2[1000, 30]], {t, 0, 1000}, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]

Function1[K1_?NumericQ, t0_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[Evaluate[X2[t] /. ndsol2[K1, t0]], {t, 0, 1000}]

NIntegrate[Evaluate[Function1[1000, t0]], {t0, 0, 100}]
```

Comment: Your symbolic solution to `System1` is correct and simplifies solution of the total problem.  However, it is not correct to substitute `X` from `System1` into `System2`, because `X` represents different quantities in the two systems, as is evident from `eqs2[[1]]`.  (The question would be clearer, if different dependent variables had been chosen for the two systems.)

Comment: @bbgodfrey , thanks a lot for that hint. It is very bad practice to use same names for different things. Now got the same result as you, did a few parts analytically.

Comment: Well done  (+1).  I too favor symbolic solutions when feasible.